# Accessing Element Array with User Input

Tags: java, arrays

i'm new in Java and i am trying to make user can get what element from arrays they're asking for.

```
int[] aksesArray = {30, 50, 10, 90, 70};
```

So if the user inputs an answer `0`, he will get access element `0` which is `30`, and so on.  And whenever the user inputs `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` the answer will always refer to 30.

i think the problem is on my a = aksesArray.length;

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class pickingArray {


public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] aksesArray = {30, 50, 10, 90, 70};

int inputElm = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Number to find an Element "));
int a = (inputElm);

a = aksesArray.length;


    if ( a == aksesArray.length ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Element you are looking for : " + aksesArray[0] );
    }
    else if ( a == aksesArray[1] ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Element you are looking for : " + aksesArray[1] );
    }
    else if ( a == aksesArray.length ) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Element you are looking for : " + aksesArray[2] );
    }
    else if ( a == aksesArray.length ) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Element you are looking for : " + aksesArray[3] );
    }
    else if ( a == aksesArray.length ) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Element you are looking for : " + aksesArray[4] );
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Element " );
    }


    }

}
```

Comment: `int a=aksesArray[inputElm];`

Answer (score 2):

You can greatly simplify your code by checking if the input number is within the range of the `aksesArray`.  In either case, you can print an appropriate message.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] aksesArray = {30, 50, 10, 90, 70};

    int inputElm = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Number to find an Element "));

    if (inputElm >= 0 && inputElm < aksesArray.length) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Element you are looking for : " + aksesArray[inputElm] );
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Element " );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does simplify the previous codes, thank you for your help.

Comment: how do i mark solved to my question that has been solved ? i'm new on here

Comment: No you can mark my answer.  Click the gray checkmark box and it will turn green.  You get 5 points for doing that I think.